# Can HTML attributes that aren't event handlers start with "on"?

Tags: html

Is it a requirement that no HTML attribute start with `on`, except for event handlers?

For example, can you place a custom HTML attribute in an element like this?

```
<span onecircle="2"></span>
```

I believe it's a rule that HTML event handler attributes always start with `on`, so I wonder whether an element like that would conclift with that.

Comment: _I don't want to dig through the HTML spec for this_ - neither do I.

Comment: I wasn't asking you, I was asking somebody else.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Whatever the reasons for asking the question, others might have the same question and would find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handler HTML content attributes start with "on" not because it is required by HTML content attribute naming rules, but because they have to [match the name of the object event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes), which themselves [have to start with "on"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers). Thus, it would follow that there is no *explicit* rules regarding whether HTML content attributes should or should not start with "on".

I also glanced/ did some searches through the "[attribute name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-name)" and "[global attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)" sections, and did not find anything regarding starting with "on" beyond what is explained above.